# URL of files at server are changed in page source in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add adsense code to a wordpress blog [demonuts.com](http://demonuts.com) . I have put google code in the **wordpress's TEXT WIDGET** . But when I run the web site the url to .js, .css or .png file is changed in view page source.

For example original url to dashicon.min.css is '**http://demonuts.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css**

but in view page source it is showing as ** http://demonuts.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.x40477.css**

It is working for some css and js files but not for js file of google code.

Original google code in **text widget** : `<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>`

code in view page source : `<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.x40477.js"></script>`

[image]

Questions

1.) From where does this x40477 is coming and why some files are still working?

2.) Google code is not working so how can I remove this x40477?

I am trying to solve this since 2 days. Plz any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: My guess is that you are using a plugin to minidy your assets. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. There was a plugin called "W3 Total Cache", which was updating URLd. After deleting it, problem is solved.

If someone found same problem as I have, try to find plugin which is most likely to be reason for such problems.